# PDF extracted text seems to be unreadable

Tags: pdf, compression

**Situation:** I've a PDF using version 1.6. In that PDF, there are several streams. There were compressed text (*Flate*) in that streams, so I decompressed these streams. After that, I extracted the *Tj*-parts of the corresponding, decompressed streams. I assumed that there would be readable text between the brackets before the *Tj* command, but the result was the following:

[image: Result]

**Actual Question:** As I have no idea, what I've got thre, I would like to know what type of content it is. Furthermore: Is it possible to get a plain text out of these string or do I need further information to extract plain texts?

**Further research:** The PDFs, which I try to analyze where generated by *iTextSharp* (seems to be an C# Library for generating PDFs). Don't know whether it is a relevant information, but it might be that that Library uses a special way of encrypt it's text data or something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *I assumed that there would be readable text between the brackets before the Tj command*

This assumption only holds for simple PDFs.

To quote from the PDF specification (ISO 32000-1):

> A string operand of a text-showing operator shall be interpreted as a sequence of character codes identifying the glyphs to be painted.
>
> With a simple font, each byte of the string shall be treated as a separate character code. The character code shall then be looked up in the font’s encoding to select the glyph, as described in 9.6.6, "Character Encoding".
>
> With a composite font (PDF 1.2), multiple-byte codes may be used to select glyphs. In this instance, one or more consecutive bytes of the string shall be treated as a single character code. The code lengths and the mappings from codes to glyphs are defined in a data structure called a CMap, described in 9.7, "Composite Fonts".

(Section 9.4.3 - Text-Showing Operators - [ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf))

Thus,

> *I would like to know what type of content it is.*

As quoted above, these "strings" consist of single-byte or multi-byte character codes. These codes depend on the current font's encoding. Each font object in a PDF can have a different encoding.

Those encodings may be some standard encoding (**MacRomanEncoding**, **MacExpertEncoding**, or **WinAnsiEncoding**) or some custom encoding. In particular in case of embedded font subsets you often find encodings where 1 is the code of the first glyph drawn on a page, 2 is the code for the second, different glyph, 3 for the third, different one, etc.

> *Furthermore: Is it possible to get a plain text out of these string or do I need further information to extract plain texts?*

As the encoding of the string arguments of text showing instructions depends on the current font, you at least need to keep track of the current font name (**Tf** instruction) and look up encoding information (**Encoding** or **ToUnicode** map) from the current font object.

Section 9.10 - Extraction of Text Content - of [ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) explains this in some more detail.

Furthermore, the order of the text showing instructions need not be the order of reading. The word "Hello" can e.g. be shown by first drawing the 'o', then going left, then the 'el', then again left, then the 'H', then going right, and finally the remaining 'l'. And two words need not be separated by a space glyph, there simply might be a text positioning instruction going right a bit.

Thus, in general you also have to keep track of the position of the separate strings drawn.